# Quick blox video call On Android

Tags: android, video, quickblox

I'm using quick blox to make 1-1 call. I am initializing the framework, sign up and then sign in into application session at very first time in my next log in. I'm creating session by log in function then starting the videoservice. How can other user will get a call from quick blox. Other user is registered with quickblox. How he can receive a call from quickblox?

Comment: Which platform do you use? iOS/Android/Web?

Answer (score 0):

After the registration process , we have to login into the quickblox app with "login" parameter.Once we logged in, we are able to place call and receive call, for that we have to use particular code for that like for Outgoing Call and Incoming Call. Look at the link https://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-android#Prepare_your_application_for_Android_SDK